# I created a Contact Page in Html and CSS. I want to put ContactForm and ContactInfo side by side, but on mobile devices it adjust itself top-bottom

Tags: html, css

I just created a contact Us form in HTML and CSS. I want a responsive page. In desktop everything works fine but When I try in mobile or tablet both contactForm and contactInfo shifts itself automatically into top and bottom position. I  want to put them side by side in also mobile devices. I don't know why this is happening?

there are two parts in container:

1. contactForm
2. ContactInfo

   ```css
   <style>
         * {
           margin: 0;
           padding: 0;
           box-sizing: border-box;
           font-family: "poppins", sans-serif;
         }

         .contact {
           position: relative;
           min-height: 100vh;
           padding: 50px 100px;
           display: flex;
           justify-content: center;
           align-items: center;
           flex-direction: column;
           background-color: lightgreen;
         }

         .contact .content {
           max-width: 800px;
           text-align: center;
         }

         .contact .content h2 {
           font-size: 36px;
           font-weight: 500;
           color: blue;
         }

         .contact .content p {
           font-weight: 300;
           color: blue;
         }

         .container {
           width: 100%;
           display: flex;
           justify-content: center;
           align-items: center;
           margin-top: 30px;
         }

         .container .contactInfo {
           width: 50%;
           display: flex;
           flex-direction: column;
         }

         .container .contactInfo .box {
           position: relative;
           padding: 20px 0;
           display: flex;
         }

         .container .contactInfo .box .text {
           display: flex;
           margin-left: 20px;
           font-size: 16px;
           color: green;
           flex-direction: column;
           font-weight: 300;
         }

         .container .contactInfo .box .text h3 {
           font-weight: 500;
           color: red;
         }

         .contactForm {
           
           padding: 40px;
           background: #fff;
         }

         .contactForm h2 {
           font-size: 30px;
           color: #333;
           font-weight: 500;
         }

         .contactForm .inputBox {
           position: relative;
           width: 100%;
           margin-top: 10px;
         }

         .contactForm .inputBox input,
         .contactForm .inputBox textarea {
           width: 100%;
           padding: 5px 0;
           font-size: 16px;
           margin: 10px 0;
           border: none;
           border-bottom: 2px solid black;
           outline: none;
           resize: none;
         }

           .contactForm .inputBox input[type="submit"] {
           width: 100px;
           background: #000;
           color: orange;
           border: none;
           cursor: pointer;
           padding: 10px;
           font-size: 18px;
         }

         @media (max-width: 991px) {
           .contact {
             padding: 50px;
           }
           .container {
             flex-direction: column;
           }
           .container .contactInfo {
             margin-bottom: 40px;
           }

           .container .contactInfo {
             width: 100%;
           }
         }
       </style>
   ```

   ```html
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html lang="en">
     <head>
       <meta charset="UTF-8" />
       <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
       <title>Document</title>
       </head>
     <body>
       <section class="contact">
         <div class="content">
           <h2>Reach Us</h2>
           <p>
             We would love to respond to your queries and help you succeed.<br />Feel
             free to get in touch with us
           </p>
         </div>
         <div class="container">
           <!-- contact form -->
           <div class="contactForm">
             <form action="contact.php">
               <h2>Send Query</h2>
               <div class="inputBox">
                 <input type="text" name="" required="required" />
                 <span>Full Name</span>
               </div>

               <div class="inputBox">
                 <input type="email" name="" required="required" />
                 <span>Email Id</span>
               </div>

               <div class="inputBox">
                 <input type="number" name="" required="required" />
                 <span>Phone</span>
               </div>

               <div class="inputBox">
                 <input type="text" name="" required="required" />
                 <span>Address</span>
               </div>

               <div class="inputBox">
                 <textarea name="" id="" required="required"></textarea>
                 <span>Type your Query</span>
               </div>

               <div class="inputBox">
                 <input type="submit" name="" required="required" value="Send" />
               </div>
             </form>
           </div>

           <!-- reach us -->
           <div class="contactInfo">
             <div class="box">
               <div class="icon"></div>
               <div class="text">
                 <h3>Address</h3>
                 <p>AaBbbbbbbb,<br />fdafafdfa,<br />fdafafgafa</p>
               </div>
             </div>

             <div class="box">
               <div class="icon"></div>
               <div class="text">
                 <h3>Phone</h3>
                 <p>+91 91XXXXXXXXXX</p>
               </div>
             </div>

             <div class="box">
               <div class="icon"></div>
               <div class="text">
                 <h3>Email</h3>
                 <p>asdfghjkl.gmail.com</p>
               </div>
             </div>
           </div>
         </div>
       </section>
     </body>
   </html>
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want .contactform and .contactinfo container side by side. You can do it in two simple ways

1. Instead of `flex-direction: column`, You can use `flex-direction: row`.
2. No need to write unnecessary CSS. Just remove the `flex-direction` property from the media query.

```
    @media (max-width: 991px) {
      .contact {
        padding: 50px;
      }
      /* .container {
        flex-direction: column;
      } */
      .container .contactInfo {
        margin-bottom: 40px;
      }
      .container .contactInfo {
        width: 100%;
      }
    }
```